# npm install error on Ubuntu: Refusing to install rxjs as a dependency of itself

Tags: ubuntu, npm

I use Ubuntu and try to install rxjs.

When I trying to install it via `npm i rxjs` I got error:

```
Linux 4.18.0-20-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "rxjs"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
```

npm ERR! Refusing to install rxjs as a dependency of itself

What is this and how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I happened upon the same exact problem. So, putting the solution here for anyone else who has this same problem.

The problem is simply because the name of your project in package.json is the same as the package you are trying to install. Change your project name to something else and the error will stop and you can install your package.

Comment: That's it, it seems a conflict with name of the package and project.